# Stack overflow error when do a loop inside another loop

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, stack-overflow

In a classic ASP function, when I do a loop inside another as shown in the code below I have a stack overflow error.

```
Function shift(x,y)
    shift = x
    For i = 1 to y
    shift = shift*2
Next
End Function

Function translate_url(iVal)
sAlpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-_0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
doWrite = False
iBase = 63 'DO NOT CHANGE
For i = 4 to 0 step -1
    iPos = (iVal and shift(iBase, i*6))/shift(1, i*6)
    If iPos Then doWrite = True
    If doWrite Then translate_url = translate_url & Mid(sAlpha, iPos + 1,1)
Next
End Function

arr = Split("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0",",")

For Each i In arr
response.Write(translate_url(arr(i)))
next
```

The error does not occur when I remove the loop outside the function. Eg:

```
response.Write(translate_url(arr(1)))
```

return "c".

What I need to do to make the code flows down the array and return the corresponding values ​​according to the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VBScript has a dark side. Variables scope is one of them.

When you don't declare a variable, VBScript will do it for you, free of charge or error and give it global scope.

What does it mean? Take a look in the main loop:

```
For Each i In arr
    response.Write(translate_url(arr(i)))
next
```

The `i` variable becomes global. When you have this later in the function:

```
For i = 4 to 0 step -1
    '...
Next
```

It's changing **the same `i` variable**. This is causing endless loop of function calls.

To resolve this, declare `i` locally in each function:

```
Function shift(x,y)
    Dim i
    '...
End Function

Function translate_url(iVal)
    Dim i
    '...
End Function
```

And it will be different variable and no overflow.

Comment: Brilliant! Much simpler than I could imagine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As the EVIL global variable i is used in your top level loop and in the functions shift() and translate_url(), you got what you deserve.

Evidence: Just change your loop to

```
For Each NoliMeTangere In arr
  response.Write translate_url(arr(NoliMeTangere))
next
```

Remedy: Use "Option Explicit" and Dim all local variables in your Subs/Functions/Methods.